# Zend Framework 2 Doctrine 2 paginated results

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, pagination, zend-framework2

I've taken the Doctrine 2 and ZF2 installation, with pagination, and tried to apply a search function to the method.

The album list is accessible via the usual route `http://myapp/album`

My current code appears to build a usable query using doctrine's `createQueryBuilder()`

When I give no parameters to title/artist then the result of `$qb->getDql();` is `SELECT a FROM Album\Entity\Album a` and it returns **no error** and **paginated results fine**.

My method;

```
public function indexAction()
{
  $view =  new ViewModel();

  $repository = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Album\Entity\Album');
  $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('album');
  $qb->add('select', 'a')
     ->add('from', 'Album\Entity\Album a');
  if ($this->params()->fromQuery('title')) {
    $qb->add('where','title like :title');
    $qb->setParameter(':title', '%' . $this->params()->fromQuery('title') . '%');
  }
  if ($this->params()->fromQuery('artist')) {
    $qb->add('where','artist like :artist');
    $qb->setParameter(':artist', '%' . $this->params()->fromQuery('artist') . '%');
  }
  $q = $qb->getDql();
  $paginator = new Paginator(new DoctrineAdapter(new ORMPaginator($this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($q))));
  $paginator->setDefaultItemCountPerPage(10);

  $page = (int)$this->params()->fromQuery('page');
  if ($page) $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
  $view->setVariable('paginator', $paginator);

  return $view;
}
```

But when I pass a query through the URL `http://myapp/album?title=In%20My%20Dreams` the result of `$qb->getDql();` is `SELECT a FROM Album\Entity\Album a WHERE title like :title` which returns the error below.

```
Zend\Paginator\Exception\RuntimeException
File:
/Users/luke/Sites/hotelio/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Paginator/Paginator.php:637
Message:
Error producing an iterator
Stack trace:
#0 /myapp/module/Album/view/album/album/index.phtml(20): Zend\Paginator\Paginator->getIterator()
#1 /myapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php(507): include('/myapp...')
#2 /myapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/View.php(205): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#3 /myapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/View.php(233): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#4 /myapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/View.php(198): Zend\View\View->renderChildren(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#5 /myapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/View/Http/DefaultRenderingStrategy.php(102): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#6 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy->render(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#7 /myapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#8 /myapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('render', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Array)
#9 /myapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php(347): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('render', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#10 /myapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php(322): Zend\Mvc\Application->completeRequest(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#11 /myapp/public/index.php(12): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#12 {main}
```

I understand that the error is where the view is accessing the variable, but as the paginator handles the modified query it appears to get as far of the view before erroring. I am not really sure what is going on here.

For the avoidance of doubt, the original method which also operates without error;

```
public function indexAction()
{
  $view =  new ViewModel();

  $repository = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Album\Entity\Album');

  $paginator = new Paginator(new DoctrineAdapter(new ORMPaginator($this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($repository->createQueryBuilder('album')))));
  $paginator->setDefaultItemCountPerPage(10);

  $page = (int)$this->params()->fromQuery('page');
  if ($page) $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
  $view->setVariable('paginator', $paginator);

  return $view;
}
```

Comment: try search 'In%20My%20Dreams' in controller if you get same error then it's %20 cause problem

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error. In my case the problem was "date.timezone" not being set in php.ini. This was causing the following code to actually catch a \DateTime() exception.

Zend\Paginator\Paginator

```php
    public function getIterator()
    {
        try {
            return $this->getCurrentItems();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception\RuntimeException('Error producing an iterator', null, $e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from bad DQL, "error producing an iterator" can also occur when data/DoctrineORMModule/Proxy does not have the correct write permissions set on it:

```
chmod 755 data/DoctrineORMModule/Proxy
```